# Misterious box in WordPress header

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this weird issue that I haven't been able to resolve. I added a logo to my WordPress header, by adding code to enable the option in the customizer, that caused the "a href=..." div to appear as an "invisible" empty box under the logo that I can't get rid of.

I've tried editing the CSS a hundred different ways but can't get it to disappear...

I did a fair amount of customization, but my starting point was the Underscores starter theme.

You can have a look at the website here. You'll need to use the element inspector to see the empty box:

[www.salientcity.com](http://www.salientcity.com/wp/)

Thanks!

Here is the php in my header file

```
<div class="title-box">
<?php $logo=get_theme_mod('logo');?>
    <?php if ($logo) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
    <?php } ?>
```

and here is the CSS that I'm using:

```
.header-image img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header-background-image {
    background: no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover!important;
    -moz-background-size: cover!important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover!important;
}

.header-background-image .title-box { /* Main image box in header, where logo will be */
    background: #ff9900;
    background: hsla(36, 100%, 50%);
} 
.site-branding {
    padding: 2rem 0; /* Header block padding top and bottom */
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff; /* Header block color, background of website image */
    background: hsl(0° 0% 100%)
}
.title-box {
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 75%;
    padding: 5rem 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.site-title {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: normal;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.site-description {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.site-title a,
.site-description { /* Font color of header, eventuely changed for logo */
    color: #fff;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
```

Comment: Can you specify which div class is added in your question code?

Comment: What element is this mystery box you're talking about?

Comment: Is it possible to get a screenshot or a link to your site (if it is live) to check it out?

Comment: Put up a rough copy at www.salientcity.com/wp/ Thanks Guys!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: `#masthead .title-box > a { display: inline-block; }` ?

Comment: Thanks d79 but it didn't really fix the issue. The box never really disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed something else. Please do one thing just edit you logo in photoshop and remove extra spaces from top and bottom of your logo and then upload you new logo. I hope you will not see this anchor box.

Look here is your logo with space at top and bottom. 
http://salientcity.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Salient-logo.png

Comment: Thanks for the advice Iffi, just updated to a cropped version... Still need to get rid of that annoying box though mostly because I want the logo to sit closer the the navigation menu.

Comment: Ok what you need to do go to following page I mean style sheet. *- http://salientcity.com/wp/wp-content/themes/salientcity%202/style.css?ver=4.1.1 *- Than open style.css page and find the class .site-branding
*- In this class replace existing padding: 2rem 0; with padding: 2rem 0 0;
That's all. After this your logo will be closer to nav just referesh harder. press cntl+f5

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help Iffi, worked perfectly!

Comment: PS: Looks like the problem is still there! the logo did shift down but the box is what I want to affect. I feel like it might have something to do with the function; I think that box si not supposed to load if a logo is present.

Comment: the box will not to be removed cause this is anchor tag box and its not create any problem right now I have check. This anchor was not taking any space now. the space was cause of another div's. Please accept answer if its fine for you! thanks